# How to wait until for loop which have multiple service calls inside in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am looking to stop loader only after for loop finish whole execution,

I have a loop in which I am calling metadata service to get all data for the condition checks and based on the condition I am calling save service.

I would like to wait until all save services finish before stopping the loader and showing a common success message and handle the error.

```js
save(data) {
  data.forEach(element => {
    if(element.isCreatable){
      forkJoin(this.http.getMetaData(element)).subscribe(values => {
        //condition checks
        //20 lines of code to check condition
        //if condition fulfills call save service
        if (condition) {
            forkJoin(this.http.submitData(val)).subscribe(res => {
                if (res) {
                    //success message
                    //stop loader
                }
            });
        }
    });
    } 
  });
}
```

**Update**: **Thanks BizzyBob, I Tried the answer provided but it is throwing the error "You provided undefined where a stream was expected."**

```js
function save1(data) {
  forkJoin(
    data
      .filter(val => val.isCreatable)
      .map(e => {
        console.log(e); //coming as object 
        this.http.getMetaData(e).pipe(
          switchMap(meta => {
          //20 lines of code to check condition
            if (condition) {
              return this.http.submitData(meta);
            } else {
              return EMPTY;
            }
          })
        );
      })
  ).subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log('stop loader')
  });
}
```

Comment: where's data coming from? Is it also within a stream? Where do you start the loader?

Comment: I have data already available , I am just using this method to call the service

Comment: "return" is missing before "this.http.getMetaData(e).pipe(..." in your update.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an observable that does both steps; get the metadata and calls `submitData()` if necessary.  For a single element, it would look something like this:

```js
const saveElementIfNecessary$ = getElement().pipe(
  switchMap(element => this.http.getMetaData(element)),
  switchMap(meta => condition ? this.http.submitData(meta) : EMPTY)
);

saveElementIfNecessary$.subscribe();
```

Here we use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to transform one observable to another. Notice inside `switchMap` we pass a function that returns an observable.  We do not need to subscribe, as `switchMap` handles this automatically.

Since you want to only call `submitData()` when the condition it true, we can simply return [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) (*which is an observable that immediately completes without emitting anything*) when the condition is false.

Since [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) takes an array of observables, you can map the array of elements to an array of observables like the above, that do both steps.  Then, you can simply turn off your loader after the forkJoin observable completes:

```js
forkJoin(data.map(e => this.http.getMetaData(e).pipe(
  switchMap(meta => condition ? this.http.submitData(meta) : EMPTY)
))).subscribe({
 complete: () => console.log('stop loader') 
});
```

Comment: thanks, BizzyBob, Just a question If I use switchmap then I need to return service or empty but to check condition, I do have 20 lines of code so I cannot use it in ternary operation. Is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: save1(data) {
  forkJoin(
    data.map(e => {
      if (e.isCreatable) {
        this.http.getMetaData(e).pipe(
          switchMap(meta => {
            if (condition) {
              return this.http.submitData(meta);
            } else {
              return EMPTY;
            }
          })
        );
      }
    })
  ).subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log('stop loader')
  });
}

Comment: I tried this but it is throwing an error 'you provided undefined where a stream was expected.

Comment: In your new code, you only return an observable when `e.isCreatable`; you should also return `EMPTY` when `!e.isCreatable`.

Comment: Actually, it would probably be cleaner just to filter your data for the condition `data.filter(e => e.isCreatable).map(...)` and then remove the condition inside of `map`

Comment: changed the code but still getting the same error

Comment: Hmmmmm... well, I guess you need to determine where you are returning `undefined`.   Try logging the results of your `data.filter.map` and ensure it an array of observables.  Maybe double check that `this.http.submitData()` actually returns an observable.

Comment: If no luck, try replicating in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)

Comment: actually while debugging, I found that the service call is not happening... loop is executing but it is not going inside switchMap and no service calls in the network tab

Comment: data.filter is coming as an array and after map, if I do console... element is an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await` as follow

```
async save(data) {
    await Promise.all(data.map(async element => {
      if (element.isCreatable) {
        await this.http.getMetaData(element).pipe(switchMap(values => {
          //condition checks
          //20 lines of code to check condition
          //if condition fulfills call save service
          if (condition) {
            return this.http.submitData(val).pipe(tap(res => {
              if (res) {
                //success message
                //stop loader
              }
            }));
          }
          return EMPTY;
        })).toPromise();
      }
    }));
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use async-await and Promise while you have the gift of Rxjs operators! you can benefit from using fork-join operator and highest order operators instead